# Возможно ли упростить switch на С в моей конструкции

Tags: c, switch

Сейчас изучаю оператор `switch`. Как можно упростить следующую конструкцию:

```c
switch (k%10){        
    case 1: (k==11)?printf("Мне %d лет", k):printf("Мне %d год", k); break;
    case 2: (k==12)?printf("Мне %d лет", k):printf("Мне %d года", k); break;
    case 3: (k==13)?printf("Мне %d лет", k):printf("Мне %d года", k); break;
    case 4: (k==14)?printf("Мне %d лет", k):printf("Мне %d года", k); break;
    default: printf("Мне %d лет", k);
    }
```

Мне кажется, что `case 2-4` можно упростить, так ли это?

Comment: IMHO весь фрагмент лучше переписать с использованием функции, которая будет возвращать подходящую строковую константу (т.е. "год", "года", "лет"). Получится что-то в таком духе -- `printf("Мне %d %s", k, get_years_rus(k));`. А существующий сейчас `switch` переместится внутрь функции.

Comment: `gettext` использует различные правила для номеров (потому как в переводах интерфейсов отличается), вот там и посмотрите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, можно сделать «сквозной проход» (fall-through) по меткам:

```
case 2:
case 3:
case 4: (k==12 || k==13 || k==14) ? printf("Мне %d лет", k) : printf("Мне %d года", k); break;
```

Думаю, вам нужно именно это.

Comment: Потерялся вариант printf("Мне %d год", k);

Comment: @gbg, ну у автора был вопрос по кейсам 2−4, не счел нужным весь `switch` писать.

Comment: @eanmos, спасибо большое. Думаю, что с данным вопросом разобрался благодаря Вам.

Comment: @AntonKulago, всегда рад помочь :)

Comment: Здесь нет "сквозного прохода". Это просто несколько меток в одной точке.

Comment: @AnT, формально, конечно, такая вещи как «сквозной проход» не имеет никакого определения. Но это просто условность языковой конструкции (я имею в виду русский язык), чтобы более-менее интуитивно объяснить принцип.

Comment: @AnT, в английском употребляется fall through, так что это вполне распространенный неформальный термин. Ну даже не термин, а скорее речевой оборот.

Comment: Да, о том и речь, что никакого "fall through" в вашем коде нет. Чтобы было "fall through", каждая метка должна получить свой statement без `break` в конце. Например: `case 2:; case 3:; case 4: ...;`. Вот это формально будет "fall through". У вас же просто несколько меток прицеплены на один statement. Это никакой не "fall through".

Comment: @AnT, так ведь это не имеет значения, разве нет? К примеру, в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/188493/8086115) в качестве примеров fall through приводят такой же случай. В Wiktionary приводят такое определение: «*In certain programming constructs, the situation where execution passes to the next condition in a list unless explicitly redirected*».

Comment: @AnT, единственно формальное определения, связанное с fall-through я нашел на cppreference.com — [C++ attribute: fallthrough](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/fallthrough). В примере на этой странице `case 1` тоже не содержит statements.

Comment: @AnT, вообще я проверил и Clang не выдает предупреждение на fall-through при `case` без statements. Так что вы, похоже, правы. Но я пока не понимаю, почему. Можете сказать, где найти формальное определение fall-through?

Comment: @AnT, я нашел [The fallthrough attribute](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2052.pdf). Цитата оттуда: «The fallthrough at (0) is left to QoI as to whether a diagnostic is desired or not. Common practice is for (0) to not diagnose fallthrough because there is only a single newline between the case labels.». Т. е. проход через case labels, разделенные только символами новой строки, все таки считается fall-through, но такая ситуация не обязана диагностироваться?

Comment: В примере по ссылке как раз правильно помечено комментарием то конкретное место, где происходит fallthrough: в конце `case 2`. Между `case 1` и `case 2` никакого fallthrough нет. Fallthrough происходит только между case-labels, привязанным к разным statements.

Comment: @AnT, а что на счет моего последнего комментария?